# '1 Connection Error' in student registration form after clicking on registr

Tags: java, sql, spring, sqlexception

In **Student Registration** when I give input and try to register it shows me message dialog box with:

> 1 connection error

try relay hard to solve this problem but i can't.

```
try {
    query="insert into student values('"+t1.getText()+"','"+t2.getText()+"','"+c1.getSelectedItem()+"','"+c2.getSelectedItem()+"','"+a1.getText()+"');";
    int //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="/*comment*/">
               executeUpdate
        //</editor-fold>
    ;
    executeUpdate = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Thank you "+t1.getText()+"\nYou are registered now");
} catch(SQLException e) {
    if (e.getErrorCode()==1062) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"StudentId is a primary key, duplicate entry is not allowed\nIt should be unique");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"1connection error");
    }
}
```

This is my `student Registration` database sql file.

```
INSERT INTO `student registration`(`Student ID`, `Student Name`, `Stream`, `Class`, `Address`)
VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5])
```

Comment: 1) This problem has nothing to do with your IDE or Swing (using a `JOptionPane` to report messages is irrelevant to the problem). Don't add irrelevant tags. 2) The code uses a poor way to report exceptions. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Examining the `SQLException` will give an definate answer to the actual problem. I suspect the semicolon(;) in the query is not needed.